# Открытие файлов PHP на Mobile Angular UI 1.2, возможно ли это?

Tags: angularjs

Всем привет. Решил освоить фреймворк Mobile Angular UI 1.2, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. По умолчанию в sidebar прописаны ссылки на подгружаемые файлы такого вида

```
<div class="list-group" ui-turn-off='uiSidebarLeft'>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/">Home <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/scroll">Scroll <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/toggle">Toggle <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/tabs">Tabs <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/accordion">Accordion <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/overlay">Overlay <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/forms">Forms <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/dropdown">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/touch">Touch<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/swipe">Swipe<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/drag">Drag 1<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/drag2">Drag 2<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#/carousel">Drag 3<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

После этого идет определение #/ через JS вот таким способом

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',              {templateUrl: 'style/themes/default/home.php', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/scroll',        {templateUrl: 'scroll.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/toggle',        {templateUrl: 'toggle.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/tabs',          {templateUrl: 'tabs.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/accordion',     {templateUrl: 'accordion.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/overlay',       {templateUrl: 'overlay.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/forms',         {templateUrl: 'forms.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/dropdown',      {templateUrl: 'dropdown.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/touch',         {templateUrl: 'touch.php', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/swipe',         {templateUrl: 'swipe.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/drag',          {templateUrl: 'drag.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/drag2',         {templateUrl: 'drag2.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/carousel',      {templateUrl: 'carousel.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
});
```

Расширение файлов стоит html, но нужно чтобы подгружался php файл. Возможно ли это реализовать? Обычная замена расширений не работает, происходит бесконечная подгрузка. Спасибо за внимание)

Comment: все зависит от содержания файлов, кроме того в списке как минимум два файла php уже используются

Comment: где php используется это уже сам прописывал, весь вывод идет в html. Содержание файлов какое должно быть и что не должно быть?

Comment: в роуте ангуляра нет никакой магии: он берет адрес из templateUrl - делает get запрос и получается html, ему не важно куда делать запрос к статическому файлу или нет, ему важно получить в ответ текст/html